# Find an exact function indicating the number of steps taken by the algorithm

Tags: c, function, time-complexity, big-o

```
int mystery(int n) {
    int s = 0;
    int tmp = n+1;
    for (int i; i<=n; i++) {
        s = tmp + i;
        tmp = s;
    }
    return s;
}
```

How can I determine this function and what the function does? Also, can this function be improved with respect to its running time?

Comment: `i` is not initialized, so this functions exhibits undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

There is some superfluous code in the above; `s` is completely unnecessary. Re-writing it without it makes it clearer.

```
int mystery(int n) {
    int tmp = n + 1;
    for (int i = 1; i<=n; i++) {
        tmp += i;
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

What it does is

- Set `tmp` to n + 1
- Add 1 then 2 then 3 then 4 and so on

This currently has a running time of `O(n)`. However, it turns out that there is a [constant time formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60578/what-is-the-term-for-a-factorial-type-operation-but-with-summation-instead-of-p) for `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + N`. We can use this to create the following, which is constant time.

```
int mystery(int n) {
    int triangleNumber = (n * (n + 1)) / 2;
    return triangleNumber + n + 1;
}
```

Comment: Where is `i` initialized?  It is indeterminate; there's only 'undefined behaviour'.